# PySpark Filter shows only 1 row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a 12 GB .csv file and I am trying to filter rows based on some value in a column under "AppName"

Doing this in Pyspark:

```
display(df.filter(df.AppName=="23954ec32332dfgd"))
```

only yields 1 row as opposed to at least 1400 rows.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
df1 = df.filter(df.AppName=="23954ec32332dfgd")
print df1.count()
```

Comment: If you are using python 3, then the correct way is: 
print(df1.count()) 
as stated by the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html